# Control the external program to generate output with Qt program in C++

Tags: c++, qt

I have seen a few sample of running .exe file in a Qt program but is it possible to invoke the functions in the external program?

For example, external program A is an existing application which receives input and generates output. Program A requires the users' interaction with the GUI of Program A in order to work. How do I pass the input to program A and get output for my current Qt program without showing and using the GUI of Program A.

Comment: Generally speaking, you can’t.  You can read the text printed by program A to stdout and stderr, and you can send text to A’s stdin, although it’s up to A whether it wants to read that text and do anything with it (most GUI programs don’t)

Answer (score 1):

actually you can and this is knonw in the it world as IPC
every Operating Sytem has some interfaces to allow you to do that and qt has some concrete implementations of these.  (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/ipc.html)

Inter-Process Communication in Qt

- TCP/IP
- Local Server/Socket
- Shared Memory
- D-Bus protocol
- QProcess Class
- Session Management

but this is not going to work out of the box, you need to "enable" such capabilities in your qt app and the 3rd app triggering the methods must be:

able to call IPC interfaces,
able to know what interfaces are exposed by your qt app (what is the signature of the method etc etc)

Comment: Is there any video tutorial or resources can be referred to?

Comment: about the full and actual implementation.